# SharePoint workflow Suspended with error HTTP 401 reason=Invalid audience Uri ,category=invalid_client

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, user-profile-service

2 days back we have changed our web application URL, now when I am running site workflow created on sharepoint, workflow immediately got suspended with error:

> HTTP 401 reason=Invalid audience Uri ,category=invalid_client

Answer (score 0):

- Appliaction server Go to services>>FIM and FIMS are running if not
  then start
- Sharepoint central administartion >>go to monitoring>>review job
  definitions>>1]workflow2]workflow auto clean up3]workflow fail over4]
  Refresh Trusted Security Token Services Metadata feed. >>all RUN NOw
- go to services on server>>user profile service>>restart
- Go to manage service application>>user profile service application >>
  1]configure synch timer service >>run now>>  2]start
  synchronization>>full Synchronization
- Go to workflow manager shell>>get-WFFArmStatus Get-SBFarmStatus Net
  Stop WorkflowServiceBackEnd Net Start WorkflowSericeBackend
- Go to service Restart>>1]service bus gateway 2]service bus message
  broker 3]service bus resource 4]window fabric host service5]workflow
  manager backend
- IIS>>application pool>>workflowmngt>>recycle >>and check all
  application pools
- Go to sharepoint management shell>>run as admin>>Register workflow
  service>>

  Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite "http://servername/pwa" -WorkflowHostUri "http://servername:12291" -AllowOAuthHttp -force
- Go to window power shell>>IISRESET